# Actionbarsherlock library is not working on android version 5.0 (Lollipop) and onwards?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented actionbarsherlock library in my application. Its working fine for below android version 5.0. But when I am installing same application on version 5.0(Lollipop) it is giving me below error.

Attempt to invoke virtual method '`void com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)`' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you need `ActionBarSherlock` anymore (note that it's **no longer supported** by the author)? You can use the ActionBar (or ToolBar)... For supporting the older devices there's the `ActionBarCompat`.

Answer (score 0):

setNavigationMode is depricated now, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode(int)) and ActionBarSherlock is not updated it seems.